# Get POST variables from browser control

Tags: post, browser, get, request, windows-phone-8

In my winphone application I have a Browser control and a page with HTML form in it. Is it possible to somehow extract POST variables from control after user fills in and submits a form inside it?

Trying to execute JS and bind some events to submit button is not an option. I wonder if it can be done by using standard methods and events accessible for Browser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Navigating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) would be your most likely option for getting this information, but you can [only get the Uri being navigated to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.navigatingeventargs%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). You do not get access to the Request object that is being sent to the server.